# Why are divs inserted by php overlapping?

Tags: php, html, css

I got this html Code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
include 'functions.php';
$logs = getUnsuccessfulBuilds();
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($logs); $i++){
    echo("<div class='errorlog'>");
    echo($logs[$i]['name']);
    echo($logs[$i]['id']);
    echo("</div>");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And this css code

```
body {
    background-color: #27373d;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.errorlog {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    background-color: #c6656a;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Why are the inserted elements colored, but not aligned as I want them to be? They are all at the same position, even if I change `margin`.

Comment: Remove `position: absolute;` from `.errorlog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given all of the .errorlog divs `position: absolute;`, which will absolutely position them all ontop of each other.

Comment: Thanks. That was it :)